# Prioritising labels in Tilemill?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, tilemill, cartocss

I made a map using tilemill and osm data. This map is indented for print, so it will be exported to pdf, so no zoom levels used in mss files.

I need to prioritise labels used on this map but can't figure out how. i need street names and subway stations to be always on map, and fill all unused space with amenities markers. Metro icons are made as shields

```
#spb-point [railway='subway_entrance']
  {
  shield-face-name:"Proxima Nova Regular"; 
  shield-unlock-image: true;
  shield-file: url(maki/svgs/subway-spb-15-3.svg);
  shield-name:[name];
  shield-size:10;
  shield-wrap-width:20;
  shield-halo-fill:#fff;
  shield-halo-radius:2;
  shield-text-dy:20; 
  }
```

Amenities are made as markers

```
#spb-point [amenity='school']
  {
  marker-file: url(maki/fill/svgs/college-11.svg);
  }
```

Street names are made as lines with labels

```
#spb-line [highway='primary_link'],
#spb-line [highway='primary']
{

line-width:3;
line-color:#fff;
    ::label{
  text-name: [name];
  text-margin:100;
  text-size: 10;
  text-face-name: "Proxima Nova Regular"; 
  text-fill: #000;
  text-placement: line;
  text-halo-fill: #fff;
  text-halo-radius: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-character-spacing:0.8;
  }
```

What I want to achieve is that street names and subway shields won't disappear as I export map to pdf.

[image: Here is result that I want]

[image: Here is what i get after export]